# Find element by xpath in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

When the test case with below lines is executed, i get below error -

> NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element:
>   {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@id='sizzle-1442313418270']/div/table/tbody/tr/td[3]"}

```
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='sizzle-1442313418270']/div/table/tbody/tr/td[3]").click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='sizzle-1442313418270']/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[4]").click()
```

Comment: What is unclear for you in this error?

Comment: when it comes date selection field  it showing this error.

Comment: i want to show date field  what ever i select but here test case stops when it is reaches date field and showing unable to locate element

Comment: is your field already visible?

Comment: yes my date field is visiable

Comment: Your xpath locator might be a wrong one. Can you post your html code too?

Comment: Please post what else you have tried. The XPath you are using isn't finding the element. We can't help you further unless you post the HTML you are referencing. ... and posting things like, "guys please help me" doesn't make anyone want to move any faster. We don't work for you. Ask a clear question, provide everything we need to help you, and show that you did work on your own are the best ways to get people to help you quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment so must give this as an answer.
If you are sure the element exist then before the line of execution put a `Thread.sleep (5000)` and if that works you will then know selenium is executing before element loads.  You then delete the *sleep* and wait for something else to appear on the page using explicit wait then execute the rest of the code

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
WebElement element_p = (new WebDriverWait(_driver, 3))
            .until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By
                    .xpath("//div[@id='sizzle-1442313418270']/div/table/tbody/tr/td[3]"))).click();
```

Another possibility could be that your element is in an iframe?

Answer (score -1):

Use implicit wait statement before your **date**  statement

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

It will be better to execute wait statement  after creation of firefox Constructor because before execution of findElement statement ,implicit statement will definitely run

if it doesn't work then go for explicit statement

Comment: `.implicitlyWait()` sets the default wait, it doesn't actually wait when that code is called. You should read [the docs](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#implicit-waits)